# Files deleted in mac?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I was going to move my files by copying and pasting them to another drive but the system said that there are not enough space to do that and after all of my files which were pictures has been deleted.

What do I do now to reach them again?

Comment: Files don't get deleted by copying.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you 'Cut' the files to the other drive (instead of 'Copy'), and midway through the operation the disk ran out of space.

Unless you hit the 'Delete' button, none of your pictures should've gone missing. Your missing files are likely stored on the second drive, which is the drive that warned that it is full.

---

In the long run you might want to invest in a couple* of large (1 or 2 TB) storage drives to store your files on. Swapping files to/from very full hard drives isn't going to solve the problem long-term.

<sub>* - Get two, and duplicate the files between them. That way you have a backup drive if one of them dies.</sub>